# How to import tab delimited data to sqlite using RSQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'd like to import a bunch of large text files to a SQLite db using RSQLite. If my data were comma delimited, I'd do this:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = 'my_db.sqlite')
dbWriteTable(conn=db, name='my_table', value='my_file.csv')
```

But how about with '\t' -delimited data? I know I could read the data into an R data.frame and then create the table from that, but I'd like to go straight into SQLite, since there are lots of large files. When I try the above with my data, I get one single character field.

Is there a sep='\t' sort of option I can use? I tried just adding sep='\t', like this:

```
dbWriteTable(conn=db, name='my_table', value='my_file.csv', sep='\t')
```

EDIT: And in fact that works great, but a flaw in the file I was working with was producing an error. Also good to add header=TRUE, if you have headers as I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
dbWriteTable(conn=db, name='my_table', value='my_file.csv', sep='\t')
```

Per the following toward the top of page 21 of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf

> When dbWriteTable is used to import data from a file, you may optionally specify header=,
>   row.names=, col.names=, sep=, eol=, field.types=, skip=, and quote=.
>
> [snip]
>
> sep= specifies the field separator, and its default is ','.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had actually already tried that, but it produced an error. Added details above.

Comment: First off, does your data have 11 columns? Secondly, have you taken a look around line 1922 of the file to see if maybe it's got extra delimiters (tabs in this case)?

Comment: Yeah, prob something weird in that line. I just tried reading in one of the other files and it worked.

Comment: Are the questions and answers spam? Same code in question and same answer worked...